# How to install and configure appium in ubuntu?

Tags: npm

I have already install and configure appium in windows platform.
I want to do the same in ubuntu. I have searched for some blogs and find some useful. Please tell me the way to install and configure appium in ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

To install `appium` in Ubuntu follow these commands

First install the required dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Now install `linux brew` with `ruby`

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

Set up $PATH for `linux brew`

```
gksu gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Now add these lines to the end of the file and save it

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Now use `linux brew` to install `node`

```
brew update
brew install node
brew link node
```

Now we can install `appium`

```
npm install -g appium
npm install wd
```

To run `appium`, just use

```
appium
```

I appropriated this guide from an [Ubuntu blog post](http://ubuntubegin.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu.html) by [Dharma Krish](https://plus.google.com/111549520929411693049/posts), credit to them.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if this is the answer you are looking for please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to find the right answer, if not, please say why.